# Applying navigation drawer throughout the app in Android?

Tags: android

I had an app which was developed 2 years back, now I want to add navigation drawer to that app, but the problem is in that app there are 15 Activities, so do I need to apply the Navigation drawer for all 15 Activities? or is there best way to implement this.?
The navigation drawer items are common for whole app.
Can anyone suggest me the best way to implement this.

Comment: Better convert your app to use fragments. I mean, 15 activities, really? :)

Answer (score 0):

A way you can do it, since Navigation Drawers are just list fragments, is create a list fragment and recall that same fragment in all the activities that you want it in. You can do this using the XML Layout Editor to place the fragment in the layout.

Having so many activities, however, makes it a lot of work (especially if your app is designed for multiple sizes and each activity has a layout).